Arranging the numbers $0$ to $n$, with specified gaps between duplicates
Consider a collection containing each of the numbers $1,2,...,n$ exactly twice and $0$ exactly once. So the collection has size $(2n+1)$. We want to arrange these numbers in a list in such a way that for all $m \in \{1 ,...,n\}$ there are exactly $m$ numbers between the two $m$'s. For which $n$ is this possible?
I've tried to find solutions by hand. So far, I have found solutions for $n=1,2,3$:

For $n=1$, we consider the collection $(0,1,1)$ 
One such arrangement which satisfies the condition is $(1,0,1)$ i.e. between the two $1$s, there is exactly one number

For $n=2$, we consider the collection $(0,1,1,2,2)$ 
One such arrangement which satisfies the condition is
$(1,2,1,0,2)$ i.e. between two $1$s, there is exactly one number, and between two $2$s, there are exactly $2$ numbers

For $n=3$, we have a solution $(3,1,2,1,3,2,0)$ - credit @Cyclotomic Field


So I have solutions for $n=1,2,3$.
I've tried to spot a pattern between these solutions so I can generalize to a construction for any $n$ but I haven't been able to find one so far.
I'm hoping there is a simple construction.

I've made changes based on the above comments. Do you think these issues are now resolved and are any other changes required to get this question reopened? @D.W.

@AdamDougall, Looks great to me, and it looks like reviewers have agreed as this has been re-opened.  Thank you for your work improving the question, I think it helped a lot!

This is very close to "Langford sequences". Quoting from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LangfordsProblem.html Langford's problem is "Arrange copies of the $n$ digits $1, \dotsc, n$ such that there is one digit between the $1$s, two digits between the $2$s, etc.... Davies (1959) showed that solutions to Langford's problem exist iff $n\equiv0,3 \bmod4$." The only difference is that you also include zero.

A construction for $n$ even:
$(n-1,n-3,...1,n,1,...,n-3,n-1),(n-2,n-4,...,2,0,n,2,...,n-4,n-2)$
And a similar construction for $n$ odd:
$(n-1,n-3,...2,n,0,2,...,n-3,n-1),(n-2,n-4,...,1,n,1,...,n-4,n-2)$
In both cases, we nest the even numbers inside each other and put $n,0$ in the centre, and nest the odd numbers with $n$ in the centre. Then we put these two nests next to each other so that in between $n$ and $n$, we have all the numbers from $0$ to $n-1$.
